# Why are functions used for classes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small library to build objects based on specifications provided by user. They can have inheritance and many more class features.

But, my approach is different than usual approach, because I'm not using functions as classes.

This is an example of a created object:

```
var objectTest = {
    someVar: 5,
    someMethod: function () {...}
};
```

This is really what I want to have. But, all other class implementations have a different approach. All of them end up having functions as classes.

---

Edit: (For clarification)

Usual approach:

- Use a function as class.
- Create new functions using "new className()" and use them as objects.

My approach:

- Use library to specify base values/methods and how they're inherited from each other.
- Create new objects using "myLib.create('className')" and use them as objects.

---

I can understand the reasoning behind it, it's probably more logical to make use of prototypes.

But I'm wondering if my approach has any shortcomings that I can not see, or maybe what I'm doing is called something else.

Any help or criticism is welcome.

Comment: Everything in javascript is objects, "class-based javascript" is simply a class-like interface to manage objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has those shortcomings compared to the use of prototypes :

- you define a new function for each value of your object : this slows the creation of the object and this takes useless memory
- you can't define an inheritance like you do with prototype

So you're not really defining a class, as a class makes sense only if there can be instances sharing the same behavior, but only an object.

On the other hand, when you want only one "instance", what you do is perfectly fine.

The MDN proposes a [good guide on prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

---

Why I say you define a new function for each instance :

```
var obj1 = {
    someVar: 5,
    someMethod: function () {console.log(this.someVar)}
};
var obj2 = {
    someVar: 5,
    someMethod: function () {console.log(this.someVar)}
};
console.log(obj1.someMethod==obj2.someMethod); // logs false
```

While the use of prototype doesn't duplicate the function :

```
function MyClass(avar){
    this.someVar = avar;
}
MyClass.prototype.someMethod = function(){
    console.log(this.someVar);
};
var obj1 = new MyClass();
var obj2 = new MyClass();
console.log(obj1.someMethod==obj2.someMethod); // logs true
```

Comment: no, I don't define a new function for each value of the object. they are string/number/boolean or whatever. where did you get this idea? and inheritance is done internally, before this object is produced.

Comment: @jsnoob : see edit to see why I say you define a new function each time.

Comment: I understand what you mean, you're right about they're not pointing to the same function.

Comment: FWIW, the speed and memory argument is somewhat of a red herring. I've written games with thousands of objects keeping track of hundreds of DOM elements using the module pattern exclusively with no prototypical inheritance whatsoever and the game runs fine even on IE6. Plain objects are fairly lightweight. Usually, what slows you down is the number of DOM objects on the page. And you create those with `document.createElement`, not constructors.

Comment: Did you add duplicated functions to your objects ?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript just allows functions to be used as constructors of objects.

If we have this:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = "bar";
}

var b = new Foo();
alert(b.bar); "bar"
```

We've create a new object using the `Foo` function as a constructor. It's a convenience for putting some logic in the creation of the object.

---

It also lets you set up inherited values. By adding properties to the `.prototype` object of `Foo`, your new object created will inherit those properties.

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = "bar";
}
Foo.prototype.alertBar = function() {
    alert(this.bar);
}

var b = new Foo();
b.alertBar();
```

So now the `b` object automatically inherits the `alertBar` method, even though it wasn't defined explicitly on the object.

---

There's absolutely no requirement to use functions as constructors. As you know, you can just use literal syntax to create a single object.

You can also set up inheritance without using a constructor function. Say that you want some objects that should all inherit from a single set of values. You can accomplish this with `Object.create`.

```
var base = {
    foo: "bar"
};
```

Now if we use `Object.create` to make new objects, and if we pass `base` as the first argument, the new object will inherit from `base`.

```
var a = Object.create(base);
var b = Object.create(base);
var c = Object.create(base);

a.foo; // "bar"
b.foo; // "bar"
```

So you see that we can create objects without a constructor function, but still get the benefit of prototypal inheritance.

---

Finally, you can combine functions with plain objects to create new objects without actually using the function as a typical constructor. To do this, you'd just have the function return an object created with literal syntax.

```
var fooMaker = (function() {

    var getBar = function() {
        return this.bar;
    };

    return function fooMaker() {

        return {
            bar: "bar",
            getBar: getBar
        };
    };
})();
var f = fooMaker();

f.getBar(); // "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see functions used for the concept of classes is because of scope. JavaScript is function scoped, so for containment (i.e. not having namespace or type name collisions, etc.) the function is a way to capture scope. On the object definition in JavaScript, everything is basically part of a public collection. If that is the behavior you need, then your approach is fine. If you need to protect any variables or methods to make them private or scope the services to a unique namespace to avoid collisions or allow extensibility, you will need to learn about functions and closures and implement those as a service around your classes.

Here is a great post on scoping this to the module level:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/08/02/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-module-pattern.aspx

And the prototype level:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/08/03/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-prototype-pattern.aspx

Comment: You're confusing scope (and closures) and inheritance chain (often called "context" in javascript and you seem to call "prototype level"). They are completely separate things and it's best not to confuse them.